# Textarea append old text to new one jquery

Tags: jquery, html, clipboard

I have the following problem:

I want to copy paste text from textarea to html table that is working great, but I have an issue, when I trying to clean the clipboard and pasting to ti other data, the clipboard append old data to the new one, I want to destroy the old text and keep only the new one, I didn't figure out the source of the problem. Can you help me?

I'm using `val('')` to clean the textarea.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: clean the clipboard or text area?

Comment: Whats your effort/code/error?

Comment: Ok let's say I want to clear the textares: <textarea name="textarea" id="textareaid" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>

Comment: I use this function to paste data to textarea : $("#textareaid").bind("paste", function(e){
    pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text'); //.....});

Answer (score 0):

When you use html reset type input, it sets the value of all inputs in the form to the default value, which is the value rendered by the server.

You need to implement some `clean` function, and link it to your reset button.

Comment: I don't have a reset button, it's just a textarea, When I paste data from textarea to table I want the textarea to be clean and pasting other data without restoring the old one, Do you understand my issue?

Comment: You want to `cut` (Ctrl+X) the data instead to `copy` (Ctrl+C) it?

Comment: Yep like that, do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: I noticed That the problem is not with the textarea, it's the html table which concatenate the old to the nex text, I want to reload table after each pasting, thank you

Comment: I fix the problem, I reset the text variable after each pasting like that: var text=[], it's look very simple but the main problem that I didn't know the source of my problem. Thank you all